# Expectation of truncated Poisson Distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, expectation, conditional-expectation

I have found that if I have a $Y \sim \mathrm{Poi}(\lambda)$ and $Z=Y \mid Y>0$ then I say $$f_Z(k)=g(k)=Pr(Y=k\mid k>0)=\frac{\lambda^k}{k! (e^\lambda-1)}$$

Now I am trying to compute expectation, that by definiyion would be $\mathbb{E}[Z]=\sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty k g(k)$.

I am getting  $f_Z(k)=k\lambda^k/k!(e^\lambda-1)$ but I know the answer should be $e^\lambda\lambda/(e^\lambda-1)$. I am not really sure how to get here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must to compute the sum

$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }{\frac {k{\lambda}^{k}}{k!}} \left( {{\rm e}^{
\lambda}}-1 \right) ^{-1}
$$

and then you obtain

$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }{\frac {k{\lambda}^{k}}{k!}} \left( {{\rm e}^{
\lambda}}-1 \right) ^{-1}=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }{\frac {{\lambda}^{k}}{(k-1)!}} \left( {{\rm e}^{
\lambda}}-1 \right) ^{-1}= \sum _{k=0}^{\infty }{\frac {{\lambda}^{k+1
}}{k!}} \left( {{\rm e}^{
\lambda}}-1 \right) ^{-1}= \\  \lambda(\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }{\frac {{\lambda}^{k
}}{k!}} )\left( {{\rm e}^{
\lambda}}-1 \right) ^{-1}=\lambda{\rm e}^{
\lambda}\left( {{\rm e}^{
\lambda}}-1 \right) ^{-1}
$$

Comment: What should I do if it´s not 0-truncated. for example if it is r-truncated.I have found that if I have a $Y \sim \mathrm{Poi}(\lambda)$ and $Z=Y \mid Y>r$ then I say $$f_Z(k)=g(k)=Pr(Y=k\mid k>r)=\frac{\lambda^k}{e^\lambda k! (1-\sum\limits_{k=0}^r \frac{\lambda^k}{e^\lambda k!})}$$

Now I am trying to compute expectation,

$E[Y]=E[Y=k|k>r]=\frac{\lambda^k}{e^\lambda k! (1-\sum\limits_{k=0}^r \frac{\lambda^k}{e^\lambda k!})}$

Comment: Hi @peterson.  In the case r-truncated the distribution has the form  $$P \left( k \right) ={\frac {{\lambda}^{k}r!}{k!\,{{\rm e}^{\lambda}}
 \left( \Gamma  \left( 1+r \right) -r\Gamma  \left( r,\lambda \right) 
 \right) }}
$$  and the expectation is  $${\frac {\lambda\,r \left(  \left( r-1 \right) \Gamma  \left( r-1,
\lambda \right) -\Gamma  \left( r \right)  \right) }{-\Gamma  \left( 1
+r \right) +r\Gamma  \left( r,\lambda \right) }}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, how do you get those gamma distributions?

Comment: Hi @peterson, I am obtaining such results using Maple. It is possible to use Maxima or Wolfram online.  All the best.

Comment: without the gamma function: Do some algebra on the numerator to get

$$\lambda \frac{P(Y\ge r)}{P(Y\ge r+1)}=\lambda \frac{1-F(r-1)}{1-F(r)}$$
where $F $ is the cdf.